# Restrict MySQL to single database (disable dbname.tablename notation)

Tags: mysql, security

```
echo "SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename" | mysql safedb
```

The above will query "dbname", even though I specify 
"safedb" as the database, because of MySQL's syntax.

Is there any command-line option to mysql (or environment 
variable, etc) that will stop this behavior?

I want to limit queries/inserts/deletes/etc to safedb.

For reference, the webapp I'm writing: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-run-mysql-query.pl

Comment: By limiting grants for the user executing the query from the command line...

Comment: That's a good idea, but I was hoping for a more direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your database users have access to the database, they will be able to select from it.

The solution you're looking for is as Michael already mentioned, which is to control user access to the databases with user account grants.

Comment: I'm writing a webapp though, and ideally want to restrict with a mysql command-line option or environment variable. Surely, MySQL has considered this?

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand your use case... If you're writing a web app, you shouldn't really allow people to write their own queries. They should be wrapped in functions with only a few parameters being passed in.

Comment: This is where the insane part comes in. I want to allow arbitrary queries while still keeping my db safe. I've done this with sqlite3 (much easier since you can turn the entire file read-only), but want to port it to MySQL

Comment: Ok, but do you also want to allow them to connect as _any user_? Surely you must be restricting the connected user, which would then have appropriate grants.

Comment: (insane doesn't begin to describe it -- especially passing to the command line client rather than using the appropriate language API of whatever you're building your web app with)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm hoping that setting the environment variable USER should force all queries to come from a specific user. However, my permissions are really really open, so I'm restricting to dbs whose name ends in "_shared". However, the dbname.tablename hack can workaround this security measure. Additionally, all queries must start with "SELECT", and I'm using "mysql < file", not actually echoing the query on the command line (which would allow for backtick interpolation)

Comment: You can't really have "really really open" permissions and a "secure db". You can attempt to manually parse the incoming SQL statement from the user (regex the incoming data), then check the target table(s). And I wouldn't really call it a dbname.tablename "hack" so much as poor implementation

Comment: @Noah I did consider that (parsing the input), but since I'm allowing JOINs and stuff, this isn't trivial. The permissions on the "_shared" dbs is pretty tight. I just want to keep people out of the dbs I don't want to share. Is there no way to defeat this MySQL "feature"?

Comment: @barrycarter That's the exact purpose of the `GRANT` system.  You said it will be restricted to `$USER`, so it follows the `$USER` should have grants _only_ on the databases accessible to this system, only on the `_shared` databases. It then becomes impossible for the user to read from other dbs via dot notation.

Comment: I'm not very adept with perl, but looking at your code, there doesn't seem to be any passing of your username to your mysql command line at all. You can address this by adding `-u $user` (or similar) after `mysql`.  This, of course, assumes that you're passing in a read-only user that only has access to the *_shared databases

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski OK. A long time ago, I set very open permissions for any user @ 127.0.0.1, so I don't want to go through the process of limiting that, but I may have no choice.

Comment: @Noah OK, I'm an idiot. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/environment-variables.html setting the environment variable USER (which I do) should to the trick. But it apparently only works for Windows/Netware, not Linux. I was hoping for a more general solution than "-u" (if I forget the "-u", danger ensues), but I guess there isn't one for Linux.

Comment: The more general solution would be to not use the command line, and work with the mysql perl API, and opt for the connection with the read-only user for custom queries, and the primary user for pre-defined queries